# How to make Laravel Sanctum and Fortify work with Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

So I am really stuck in my project, where I want to create an app where the frontend would be Vue 3 and the backend would be Laravel. I know I have to use Laravel Sanctum and Laravel Fortify to make authentication working with my SPA. I watched all of the videos, like all of them and visited all the sites Google gave me and I still can't understand how to make it work. I usually get back an HTML response with the content of the welcome.blade.php file. Do I have to call the '/sanctum/csrf-cookie' axios call every time I want to communicate with the backend or do I have to do that only once? How does even logging out work? How to ask the backend if the user is logged in or not?

I appreciate all the comments and all the advice.